# Output the subset of instances used to train each base_estimator of a BaggingClassifier

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using decision stumps with a BaggingClassifier to classify some data:

```
def fit_ensemble(attributes,class_val,n_estimators):

    # max depth is 1
    decisionStump = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', max_depth = 1)

    ensemble = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator = decisionStump, n_estimators = n_estimators, verbose = 3)
    return ensemble.fit(attributes,class_val)

def predict_all(fitted_classifier, instances):
    for i, instance in enumerate(instances):
        instances[i] = fitted_classifier.predict([instances[i]])
    return list(itertools.chain(*instances))

def main(filename, n_estimators):

    df_ = read_csv(filename)

    col_names = df_.columns.values.tolist()
    attributes = col_names[0:-1] ## 0..n-1
    class_val = col_names[-1] ## n

    fitted = fit_ensemble(df_[attributes].values, df_[class_val].values, n_estimators)
    fitted_classifiers = fitted.estimators_ # get the three decision stumps.

    compared_ = DataFrame(index = range(0,len(df_.index)), columns = range(0,n_estimators + 1))
    compared_ = compared_.fillna(0)
    compared_.ix[:,n_estimators] = df_[class_val].values

    for i, fitted_classifier in enumerate(fitted_classifiers):
        compared_.ix[:,i] =  predict_all(fitted_classifier,df_[attributes].values)
```

I would like to inspect the random subset used to train each decision stump. I have looked at the documentation for both the ensemble and decision tree class, but haven't found any attributes or methods that yield the training subset. Is this a futile task? Or is there some way, perhaps while the tree is training, to output the training subset?

I am very new to pandas, but come from an R background. My code is definitely not optimized, though I can assure that the dataset is very small for my task. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have answered my own question. the estimators_samples_ attribute of DecisionTreeClassifier is what I want.